# SAS SCSI Converter

Tags: hard-drive, sas, sata

I recentely bought a Seagate Cheetah 146GB SAS ST3146755SS 10K Performance 15K RPM Hard Drive from EBAY and do have a computer that supports SAS.  The problem is that I need to convert it into a SATA connection.  I've found several adapters on EBAY, but most the folks selling it say that it cannot work with my drive.  My question is, can I convert the connection into a SATA one and with what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your computer supports SAS, why do you need to convert it to SATA?

If you don't have an SAS HBA in your computer (either onboard or as a separate PCIe card), you can't use the disk (it's not possible to run a SAS disk with a SATA controller, but the other way round often works). If you have an SAS HBA, you don't need to convert anything.

Comment: Yep.  I just realized my big derp!